# Crystal Reports Object Positions in Millimeters

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

What I want is: Set the object positions in millimeters, lets say I want the field {Document}
must print in 1 centimeter (10 millimeters) from the top, and 1 centimeter for the left,
but i cant make it.

This is what I have:

```
//rpt is a report class: ReportClass rpt, passed as parameter

Section Seccion = rpt.ReportDefinition.Sections[0];
            foreach (Formato item in f)
            {
                ReportObject Objeto = Seccion.ReportObjects["Document1"];
                Objeto.Top = 10; //Millimeters
                Objeto.Left = 10; //Millimeters
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Positions are not set in millimeters or centimeters but in [TWIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip). You can get TWIPs by multiplying the millimeter-amount by approx. 57. In your example this should lead to

```
Objeto.Top = 570; //TWIPS
Objeto.Left = 570; //TWIPS
```

I suggest to create a converter-function for this.